# How to manage few project's codebases in one Assembla repository space?

Tags: git, version-control, assembla, repository-design

Yesterday I signed for private free Assembla account. I want to use it to manage few small projects. It seems to me good idea to have only one Assembla repository space for all of my small (php) projects that would be running on one web server - different sub domains.

But I do not know how to manage different tag for different projects in git using one repository. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would rather suggest to add a git repository tool for each project in your space. That way repositories will be different, but they will all be in the same space - with url's like git@git.assembla.com:space.project1.git, git@git.assembla.com:space.project2.git, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you are tagging, but if I were tagging releases, I would tag multiple projects in a release with this schema: PROJECT_NAME_ABBREV-DATE-TIME

So some example:

ASD-2013.01.12-1251

WWW-2013.01.12-1511

BJN-2013.02.22-0124

Doing this will allow you to have some nice functionality of tags:

git tag | grep PROJECT_NAME_ABBREV

You can tell how when a tag was made by looking at it, and you can split tags up for searching, etc.

The Assembla pull down will allow you to search and filter these tags easily as well.

Your tags will also be readable and manageable.

(Assembla does allow you to have multiple git repos in 1 space, however that is not what you asked, I would prefer to segregate each project into a different repo)

Comment: Yes, it seems to me too that having separate repository for each project is much better.